# How do you clean dust from the inside of a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a 2010 MBP and lately I've noticed dust showing up underneath the keys and above under the screen hinge. I've looked at the ifixit.com tutorials [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Unibody_Mid_2010) but they don't have any guides on how to clean dust. I also have AppleCare, but [this thread](http://www.fluther.com/15968/does-an-apple-care-plan-cover-cleaning-my-computer/) mentions it doesn't cover cleaning dust. I imagine "dusty" would be subjective, but they could give you 2 cleans a year or something. Can anyone verify that they don't clean dust from parts? In the end I'll probably open it up and use a dust-buster, but thought it'd be good to check first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, on a 2010 MacBook pro, there is no way to separate the keyboard from the top case without disassembling the entire machine. The best way to clean out those keys is to get some compressed air and go to town on it.